# Java Comparator Related

Tags: java

I am new to Java so wanted to confirm that can we have different type of objects
in compare method while implementing comparator interface.
Like.  compare(Employee ,Department). or evertime we will pass same type of object Ex, Either Employee or Department. It will be helpful for me if you give answer in details.
Please confirm me .Thanks in Advance
Shahid

Comment: why would you want to do that ?

Comment: by implementing the inteface comparable

Comment: You can compare them as `Object`s. All objects in Java inherit from the `Object` class.

Comment: If you want to do this, you're probably best to make `Employee` and `Department` extend a common base class, and put the comparison code in the base class.  An alternative would be to use a `Comparator<Object>` with some logic to identify which types of objects it's dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a method like:

```
int compare(Object a, Object b);
```

and compare oranges to apples if you wish. If you need to be a bit more strict, you can (should!) define something that the compared object need to have in common. Then you can start with an interface:

```
public interface CorporateObject
{
    int getUselesnessFactor();
}
```

and then make both your Employee and Department classes implement it:

```
public class Employee implements CorporateObject
{...

public class Department implements CorporateObject
{...
```

Finally, the compare method would look like:

```
public int compare(CorporateObject a, CorporateObject b){
    if(a.getUselesnessFactor() < b.getUselesnessFactor()) return -1;
    if(a.getUselesnessFactor() > b.getUselesnessFactor()) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

You would be using this method like this:

```
int result;
Employee boss = new Employee();
Employee john = new Employee();
Department nosepickers = new Departement();
Department slackmasters = new Department();

result = compare(boss, john); // employee to employee
result = compare(nosepickers, slackmasters); // dept to dept
result = compare(boss, nosepickers); // employee to dept
result = compare(slackmasters, john); // dept to employee
```

etc.

Comment: Cant we pass Employee and Department reference to compare(Employee emp, Department dept) instead of CorporateObject, I think this should also work...If i am wrong pls help me to understand your concept (corporateObject a,CorporateObject b)..As per your code my understanding is that compare method always take same type of refernece. Pls help

Comment: see the edited answer - you can pass both in any combination. That's what the interface is for - the compare method does not care what exactly CorporateObject you pass, as long as they implement the common interface.

Comment: Thank you for valuable comments. It helped me a lot to understand the concept more clear..